# how is caption / title in cygwin terminal window generated/defined?

Tags: terminal, cygwin

When I am on local machine caption/title is like `$(pwd)`. When I am connected to other machine (using ssh) caption is sometimes like `user@masine:$(pwd)` and sometimes stay unchanged.

What is mechanism behind this behavior? Could I change it somehow (without changing source code of terminal and rebuild it)?

Answer (score 1):

The prompt and the windows title can be changed in bash setting the PS1 variable

For example on my 32bit Cygwin the setting is

```
$ echo $PS1
\[\e]0;i686 \w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\ni686 $
```

This set both the prompt and the title to contain the "i686" and the current directory, plus the prompt also contain the user@machine.

Further reading:
https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bash/Prompt_customization

Comment: Thanks! Although does not answer what is the mechanism it is useful information. It seems that "text" after `\[\e]0;` and before `\a` is used for title so I could for example define function in my `.bashrc` which change title:
 `title() {  export PS1="\[\e]0;$1 \a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$"; }`
Now I could use for example `title cool\ name\ \\w` to get title as <cool name> + <working directory>. But it doesn't work (of course) if I "ssh" to other machine.